# If $f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, can I write $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)+\lim\limits_{x\to a}\big[f'(a)\!\cdot\!(x-a)\big]$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I want to solve for $f(x)$ in the definition of the derivative at a point. Can I write $$f'(a)=\lim_{ x \to a }\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\quad\implies\\ \lim_{ x \to a }f(x)=f(a)+\lim_{ x \to a }\big[f'(a)\!\cdot\!(x-a)\big]\;\;?$$ I know it seems trivial since evaluating the limits in the latter equation gives $f(a)=f(a)$, but the motivation is to determine whether a linear approximation of $f(x)$ is exact *in the limit* as $x$ approaches $a$. If my reasoning is incorrect, is it possible to solve for $f(x)$ in the derivative equation?

Comment: Second summand is $0$, so, what you state is, that differentiable function is continuous.

Comment: Yes, the left implies the right. You’re effectively multiplying both sides by the limit of $x-a$ and then taking limits.

Comment: But is the multiplication property valid when the $x-a$ is inside a limit? It seems we should take the quotient of the limits first and then multiply both sides by $\lim_{x \to a}(x-a)$. However, this limit is zero which makes me wonder whether the quotient property of limits can be applied.

Comment: @BobTivnan The latter equality is technically correct, but pretty much useless since it's essentially $f(a)=f(a)$ (as you wrote). The "*motivation*" part suggests that you might misconstrue what the equality actually means. Note that the $f'(a)$ factor is wholly irrelevant there, and the similar equality $\lim_{ x \to a }f(x)=f(a)+\lim_{ x \to a }\big[C\!\cdot\!(x-a)\big]$ holds true for *any* constant $C\,$, not just for $C=f'(a)\,$.

Comment: It is not possible to "solve for $x$".  Consider that $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$ cannot be "solved for $x$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rigorous derivation would rewrite the first equation as the equivalent
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f'(a)=\lim_{ x \to a }\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},
$$
then multiply everything by $\lim_{x\to a} (x-a)$ to obtain
$$
\lim_{x\to a} (x-a) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} f'(a)= \lim_{x\to a} (x-a) \cdot\lim_{ x \to a }\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a},
$$
and finally use the property that the product of two convergent limits equals the limit of the product (on both sides):
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \big( (x-a) f'(a) \big) = \lim_{x\to a} \bigg( (x-a) \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \bigg) = \lim_{x\to a} \big( f(x)-f(a) \big).
$$
The last statement in the OP now follows from $$\lim_{x\to a} \big( f(x)-f(a) \big) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) - \lim_{x\to a} f(a) = \big( \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \big) - f(a)$$ and rearranging.

(It's a very good exercise to identify the precise facts/rules/theorems that are being used in every step.)

Comment: This seems totally legitimate, but I wonder, why are we allowed to multiply by $0=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)$?

Comment: You can multiply both sides on an equation by any quantity and the result is again a valid equation. This is not to be confused with cancelling the same quantity on both sides of an equation, where the nonzeroness is important. (Indeed, that fallacy would lead to a "proof" that every continuous function is differentiable here, or something like that.)

Comment: So by multiplying both sides by $\lim_{x \to a}(x-a)$ and rewriting the products inside a single limit on each side, you are basically working around the quotient property of limits which would be problematic since we would get division by zero?

Comment: @GregMartin: So that means the setup is not reversible? And from what I understand, any arbitrary equation (even false) maybe multiplied by $0$ to give a true equation, which must be either an implication of the initial (if it's true) or just a vacuous truth (if it's false).

Comment: @GregMartin I disagree with the first equation, as the derivative is not necessarily continuous. No need for the limit in the LHS

Comment: Careful not to misread: it's $\lim_{x\to a} f'(a)$, not $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)$.